# neo4j data modelling of an organization

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am thinking on modelling an organization in neo4j.

Organization has a core team, and different divisions.
There are internal groups within organization.
There are groups in organization through which external people interact.

I think there is no concept of sub node or node within node(using which we could have represented an org.).

Usually what is the best approach to represent in neo4j in this scenario?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would start out modelling it in the way you describe the domain above, so you would have a domain like:

```
(org:Organization), (team:Team), (div:Division), (group:Group)
```

And then interconnect them in the way you describe their relationships:

```
(org)-[:CORE_TEAM]->(team),
(org)-[:DIVISION]->(div),
(org)-[:INTERNAL_GROUP]->(group),
(org)-[:EXTERNAL_GROUP]->(group)
```

Depending on the use case for internal/external groups, you may want to add more general relationships, and have the rels above denote specific connections, so you could have:

```
(team)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(org),
(div)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(org),
(group)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(org)
```

It all depends on what your domain case is, like what questions you'd like to ask the data.